# How to verify if zookeeper server is in sync with the cluster after restart

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have implemented zookeeper cluster using kubernetes stateful set.
what i need is a reliable readiness check which will tell if the zookeeper server is in sync with the cluster after restart and it is not missing any data before it start serving the traffic.
what zookeeper metric can be used to reliably check this condition ?

zookeeper version i am using is 3.6.1